# Error in connecting localhost

Tags: android, httpconnection

I know this question has been asked for several times, but I am helpless now.

I have a php webpage at localhost that echo "Hello". (working perfect at localhost).
 I have following code that displays response from localhost web page to TextView in my app.

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTest);
InputStream is = null;
String result = "";
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2/android/try.php";
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {               
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        Log.d("myapp", "response " + response.getEntity());

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        String st = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    tv.setText(result.toString());
```

I am getting following error (LogCat).

```
09-24 13:34:42.654: E/log_tag(2032): Error in http connection android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
09-24 13:34:42.654: E/log_tag(2032): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**P.S** I have added Internet permission in Manifest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do network operations (connection and so on) from a different thread than the main (UI) thread. That's what the error `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` you are getting means.

You should look either into ASyncTask or Thread to do that.

Read [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html) too...

Replace the code you currently have with this:

```
    AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> my_task = new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute() {
            TextView  tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTest);
            tv.setText(result.toString());
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            InputStream is = null;
            String result = "";
            String url = "http://10.0.2.2/android/try.php";
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            try {
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                Log.d("myapp", "response " + response.getEntity());

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                String st = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }

            // convert response to string
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks Matthieu, But I have been unable to run it using AsyncTask. Can you please assist me in making AsyncTask class of the above-written code?

Comment: Thanks, but now I am getting this error :(
    09-24 15:30:10.095: E/log_tag(7027): Error converting result java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: what line is the error at ? Can you post more of your code? Maybe you should consider this problem solved and start a new question with your new problem...